# How can a classic pipeline deploy to a stage if either stage A OR stage B succeeded?

Tags: azure-devops

I have stages A, B, and C. I want stage C to deploy if stage A OR stage B succeeded. But when I use the "After Stage" deployment trigger for stage C, it only allows me to trigger deployment if stage A AND stage B succeeded. (This is a classic pipeline) Is there a way to do this?

I've considered simply having two identical stage Cs, (One after A, and one after B) but that would quickly lead to me needing a large number of duplicate stages and create Tech Debt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can a classic pipeline deploy to a stage if either stage A OR stage B succeeded?

The directly way is add two identical stage Cs, (One after A, and one after B).

But if this is not your choice. There is an another workaround is to use [Update Release Environment rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release%20environment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to trigger the stageC when the stage B succeeded. See below steps:

1, Set **C** stage only be auto triggered after **A** stage.

[image]

2, Go the **security** page of your release edit page.
[image]

Set the **Manage deployments** to **allow** for account **yourProjectname Build Service(Your Organization)**. This persmission will allow you to update the release environment in the release pipeline.

[image]

3, Go to **B** stage-->In the Agent job section-->Check `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token`. This setting will allow you to use the accesstoken in the release pipeline.

[image]

4, After above preparation, you can now add a script task at the **end of B stage** to call the release rest api. See below example in powershell task:

```
#Get releaseresponse
$Releaseurl= "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{yourOrg}/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/Release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId)?api-version=6.0-preview.8" 

$releaseresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(system.accesstoken)"} -ContentType application/json -Uri $Releaseurl

#Get the environment ID of C stage from the release response:
$id = $releaseresponse.environments |  Where-Object{$_.name -match "API-Test"} | select id

#Create the JSON body for the deployment:
$deploymentbody = @" 
{"status": "inprogress"} 
"@
#Invoke the REST method to trigger the deployment to C stage:
$DeployUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{yourOrg}/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId)/environments/$($id.id)?api-version=6.0-preview.7" 

$DeployRelease = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -ContentType application/json -Uri $DeployUrl -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(system.accesstoken)"} -Body $deploymentbody
```

Above scripts first call [get Release rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the environment id of **C** stage.
Then call the update release environment rest api to trigger the deployment to **C**.

So that above script can achieve the **C** stage be triggered after **B** stage is successfully.